# Split string of filenames into an array

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get a listing of all the files in a specific directory (/myfiles) and then sftp them to another server. The number of files will vary and so will their names -- they will look like this: 
Code Translation Table_c_Primary Relationship Type
Code Translation Table_e_Transaction Type

I was trying to put all them into an array then do a while loop (based on count) with an sftp put command. However, I can't seem to get this string into an array.

Here is what I have:

```
export directory=`find -name *Table_\*`
IFS="./"
read -a filearry <<< "${directory}"
```

During testing only ${filearry[0]} is populated. Output of echo ${filearry[0]} is:

```
Code Translation Table_c_Primary Relationship Type
Code Translation Table_e_Transaction Type
Code Translation Table_f_Appeal Code
Code Translation Table_g_Campaign Codes
Code Translation Table_h_Designation Code
Code Translation Table_i_Designation Purpose
Code Translation Table_j_Address Types
Code Translation Table_k_Degree of Graduation
Code Translation Table_l_Relationship Type
Code Translation Table_m_Activity Role
Code Translation Table_n_Activity Status Club
Code Translation Table_o_Participation Category
Code Translation Table_p_Activity Status Organization
Code Translation Table_q_Restriciton Code
Code Translation Table_c_Primary Relationship Type
```

Edit: This needs to be an automated script kicked off by cron. I'm not forced into using sftp, but whatever way I use it has to be secure.

I ended up just simplifying the script to upload all the files in the directory no matter what the name is. I have the output going to a log file which is sent as an text email to a couple people in my office. The format of this email isn't great. All the files are listed on the same line making it hard to read -- Is this fixable?

```
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; 
then 
    printf "=====================================================\n"
    printf " $DIR contains files.\n"
    printf "=====================================================\n"
    sftp username@sftp.server.com:/upload <<EOF
    put -r /myfolder/*
    quit
EOF
    printf "=====================================================\n"
    printf "Done transfering files.\n"
    printf "=====================================================\n"
else 
    printf "No files to upload in $DIR"
fi

mailx -s 'Document Feed' robert@company.com < /var/log/docfeed.log
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `sftp` or would an alternative such as `scp` (or even `rsync`) be acceptable?

Comment: [@Robert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/254988/robert) Are your the owner of the original post?

Comment: @Robert It looks like you've created two accounts. I'd advise that you merge them so you don't need your edits to be approved. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: aha! I can make comments now!! Thanks for link Anthony!

Answer (score 2):

You get an array of filenames like this:

```
filenames=( *Table_* )
```

---

Assuming you can't just use `scp` to copy all the files with

```
scp *Table_* user@host:dir/
```

you can create a batch script for `sftp`:

```
printf 'put "%s"\n' *Table_* | sftp user@host:/dir
```

If you'd like to rename them on the destination, for example replace all spaces with underscores (using the pattern substitution `${parameter//pattern/string}`):

```
for name in *Table_*; do
    printf 'put "%s" "%s"\n' "$name" "${name// /_}"
done | sftp user@host:/dir
```

---

Another obvious solution is to create an archive of the relevant file and the transfer this archive to the other host:

```
tar -cf archive.tar *Table_*

echo 'put archive.tar' | sftp user@host:/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm splitting hair here but fwiw, to accomplish what I originally wanted to do I can use:

```
 shopt -s nullglob
 documentarray=(*Translation*)
 for i in "${documentarray[@]}"
 do
 #sftp stuff here

 done
```